# How to obtain the length of VARCHAR2 attribute declared in Oracle Object Type, using OracleTypeCHAR metadata, regardless of database character set

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, metadata

My Java application depends on Oracle Object Types metadata. I use `oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCHAR` class to access these metadata with JDBC. After converting the database to charset `AL32UTF8`, the `OracleTypeCHAR#getLength()` method returns results multiplied by factor of 4 comparing to what is declared in Oracle Object Type - for example:

```
some_attribute varchar2(10)
```

Would result in lenght `40`, when lenght `10` was returned with the previous charset. Is there a way to obtain the raw value from PL/SQL without parsing OOT source code?

Comment: Are you trying to get the length in characters or in bytes?  Depending on the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS, a VARCHAR2(10) in Oracle may declare a variable that can store 10 characters of data (up to 40 bytes in the AL32UTF8 character set) or a variable that can store 10 bytes of data.

Comment: I'm trying to get the length in characters. I need this metadata in order to generate JSR-303 (e.g. @Size(max = 10)) annotations, which are applied to fields of Java entities reflecting corresponding OOT. For now my generator is configured with db-specific factor for dividing each value returned by OracleTypeCHAR#getLength() method. I assume this factor should also be retrieved by oracle specific JDBC extensions, however I don't know how. Anyway the default behavior of OracleTypeCHAR#getLength() method seems counterintuitive to me.

Answer (score 3):

The character length for a character column can be found in **user_tab_columns.CHAR_LENGTH**,

```
select column_name, comments from all_col_comments where table_name = 'USER_TAB_COLUMNS';

COLUMN_NAME          COMMENTS

TABLE_NAME           Table, view or cluster name
COLUMN_NAME          Column name
DATA_TYPE            Datatype of the column
DATA_TYPE_MOD        Datatype modifier of the column
DATA_TYPE_OWNER      Owner of the datatype of the column
DATA_LENGTH          Length of the column in bytes
DATA_PRECISION       Length: decimal digits (NUMBER) or binary digits (FLOAT)
DATA_SCALE           Digits to right of decimal point in a number
NULLABLE             Does column allow NULL values?
COLUMN_ID            Sequence number of the column as created
DEFAULT_LENGTH       Length of default value for the column
DATA_DEFAULT         Default value for the column
NUM_DISTINCT         The number of distinct values in the column
LOW_VALUE            The low value in the column
HIGH_VALUE           The high value in the column
DENSITY              The density of the column
NUM_NULLS            The number of nulls in the column
NUM_BUCKETS          The number of buckets in histogram for the column
LAST_ANALYZED        The date of the most recent time this column was analyzed
SAMPLE_SIZE          The sample size used in analyzing this column
CHARACTER_SET_NAME   Character set name
CHAR_COL_DECL_LENGTH Declaration length of character type column
GLOBAL_STATS         Are the statistics calculated without merging underlying partitions?
USER_STATS           Were the statistics entered directly by the user?
AVG_COL_LEN          The average length of the column in bytes
CHAR_LENGTH          The maximum length of the column in characters
CHAR_USED            C is maximum length given in characters, B if in bytes
V80_FMT_IMAGE        Is column data in 8.0 image format?
DATA_UPGRADED        Has column data been upgraded to the latest type version format?
HISTOGRAM
```

Use this query to find the character length of the column,

```
select
  char_length
from
  user_tab_columns
where
  table_name = 'T' and column_name = 'SOME_ATTRIBUTE';
```

Comment: I would like to retrieve this metadata for oracle object type attribute, not for table column.